# Why does code when inspecting in browser is so different from code in js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

At first, i'm sorry for my poor English.
In my rails project, I have some code of or condition in my js file like this:

```
if ((self.dataReport.length == self.rangeDate.length)
  || (type_of_cohort != 'churnrate'))
```

When running on local, it works perfectly. But when running in production environment, rails compile all js files in to one file and i got a different code for or condition i wrote above. The code is like this:

```
t.dataReport.length != t.rangeDate.length && "churnrate" == i
```

I don't understand how my code can be converted to that. Obviously, the latter code will work in the wrong way. Somebody please tell me why, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has been [minified](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)).

> Minification (also minimisation or minimization), in computer programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code without changing its functionality.

In the case of Rails, this is done by the [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). The process is very common and well-understood. It's very rare for minified code to exhibit errors not present in the original code. If you're seeing errors in production that you don't see in development it's unlikely that minification is the cause, and you should post a question describing the actual error you're seeing.

Comment: Note that the minification process doesn't *only* "remov[e] all unnecessary characters", it also changes the structure (e.g., replacing a simple `if` with `||`) - but where the new, shorter structure produces the same result as the original code.

Comment: Thank for answering my question. In my case, it is no error caused by minification, It just doesn't work as i expected. For example:
if dataReport.length = 5, rangeDate.length = 6 and type_of_cohort = 'churnrate', "self.dataReport.length == self.rangeDate.length
  || type_of_cohort != 'churnrate'" will return false and "t.dataReport.length != t.rangeDate.length && "churnrate" == i" will return true (in this case, the Asset Pipeline compiled "t" as "self" and "i" as "type_of_cohort"). I did search on google for hours, it seems like no one got this problem before.

Comment: Finally, i figure out that the code is right but it's expression make me confuse. Thank for your support.